# Embedding Image Editor in ADF page

Tags: oracle-adf

My requirement is that I shall be able to render an image in ADF page as well as can scale the rendered image, edit it, rotate in as necessary.

Does ORACLE ADF gives me out of the box support for that.

Note: I want to use something like this for image editing

http://jdevadf.oracle.com/adf-richclient-demo/faces/components/hierarchyViewer.jspx#%2Fcomponents%2FrichTextEditor.jspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing like that in ADF.

You'll have to write your own component using a lot of Javascript to handle all that functionality.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing like that in ADF.

BUT you can use one of [numerous jQuery plugins](http://shinylittlething.com/2009/02/20/image-manipulation-jquery-plugins/) to address your needs.